# Configure my web server to expose the separate folders as separate web servers?

Tags: linux, server

How can I configure my web server to make the 5 separate folders as 5 different separate web servers?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what HTTP daemon you are using, but with Apache you probably want to look at using Name Based Virtual Hosts - http://www.tecmint.com/apache-ip-based-and-name-based-virtual-hosting/